# logstash costume grok with if else condition

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Example Logs :

> 322031044530043A4    901129
>
> 322031044530043A4    901129_N12
>
> 322031044530043A4    9011293N12
>
> 322031044530043A4    901129   N12

I'd like to get

**1st log :**

> data1 : 32203104453
>
> data2 : 00
>
> data3 : 43
>
> data4 : A4
>
> data5 : 901129

**2nd log :**

> data1 : 32203104453
>
> data2 : 00
>
> data3 : 43
>
> data4 : A4
>
> data5 : 901129_N12

**3rd log :**

> data1 : 32203104453
>
> data2 : 00
>
> data3 : 43
>
> data4 : A4
>
> data5 : 9011293N12

**4th log :**

> data1 : 32203104453
>
> data2 : 00
>
> data3 : 43
>
> data4 : A4
>
> data5 : 901129    N12

**my experiment :**
[image]

**my ouput fail :**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: Instead of pictures of your code, you should post the code itself.